# why does this mysqli insert does not work?

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I am trying to use mysqli in object orientated way, this is the code:

```
class conect {
   function populate( ) {
         while ($row = $this->result->fetch_object()) { $this->data[] = $row; }
       $this->result->close();
   }
   function conect( ) {
     $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'todo');  
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
           printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
           exit();
           };
   }
   function register($name, $email, $password ) {
     $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO user (name, email, password) 
        VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$password')");
   }
 }
```

The register function is the problem, if I add that query in the conect() function it does work, but as it id does not work,no error is displayed

I have been trying to learn object orientated php and mysqli. I have managed to use the above style to create a dynamic portfolio, but this is the first time I tried to write to DB so I dont know whats the problem

Hope you can help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't display any errors, so, no wonder there are no errors displayed.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (name, email, password) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$password')";
if (!$mysqli->query($sql)) {
    trigger_error($mysqli->error);
}
```

but, to let you know, your code has nothing to do with mysqli and oop anyway.

Comment: what did not make any difference. What do you mean my code has nothing to do with mysqli and oop

Comment: you don't use mysqli features like prepared statements. so, it remains the same as old mysql. your class makes no sense, so, it's not oop either

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your variable `$mysqli` inside your `register()` method isn't defined. This also means that you cannot call any method from "nothing". Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);`at the top of your script to see warnings about undefined variables.

To solve this problem you want to save the MySQLi object in an object field and access it with `$this->mysqli` or sth. That way you can set it in your `connect()` method and use it in your `register()` method.